# Does $f$ belong to $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The fourier transform of $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ is given by $\displaystyle\hat f ( s) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \exp(-2\pi ix s) \mathrm{d}x.$ Suppose $\hat f \in L^2,$ is it true that $f \in L^2?$

As I did not get any counter examples to disprove, I have tried prove this unsuccessfully :

We have $\displaystyle\lVert \hat f \rVert_2 = \int |\hat f(s) |^2\mathrm{d}s = \int \left|\int f(x) \exp(-2\pi ix s) \mathrm{d}x\right|^2 \mathrm{d}s $ is finte.
We have to show that the integral $\displaystyle\int |f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x$ is finite.
If Fourier inversion holds we may write $\displaystyle\int |f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x = \int \left| \int \hat f (s) \exp(2i \pi s x)\mathrm{d}s\right|^2\mathrm{d}x$ but I am not able to proceed here. Also, I am not sure, if fourier inversion holds for $L^1$ functions.

Comment: @FShrike
  But how do we know that $\lVert f \rVert_2$ is fintite given that $f \in L^1?$

Comment: Honestly I’m not sure. I’m not experienced in Fourier analysis and don’t know the precise hypotheses of things like the Plancherel formula

Comment: The Fourier transform maps $L^1\cap L^2$ into $L^2$, and is an isometry in the $L^2$ norm.  Since $L^1\cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$, the Fourier transform extends to $L^2$ in an abstract form by taking limits of Cauchy sequences, but not by the formula.  For $L^1$, the Fourier transform maps it into $C_0$ and $C_0$ is the enveloping $C^*$ algebra of the involutive Banach algebra $L^1$ equipped by convolution and a compatible involution under this transform.

Answer (score 4):

In brief, yes, for $f\in L^1$, if $\widehat{f}\in L^2$, then $f$ itself is/was in $L^2$.

As you rightfully worry, this does not follow just by computing the Fourier inversion integral... since $\widehat{f}$ may fail to be in $L^1$, so the integral has convergence problems.

As @JohnDoe commented, in fact the general definition of the Plancherel extension to $L^2$ of the Fourier transform is not by an integral, but by taking $L^2$ limits (of Fourier transforms computed by literal integrals) from $L^2\cap L^1$.

More abstractly, if one wants, $L^1$ functions give tempered distributions, so lots of Fourier transform stuff works out fine, though not by direct, literal integrals.